# Function in Pine Script with break

Tags: function, for-loop, pine-script

I have a function in pine script:

```
fun_check(Sell_Signal) =>
    Base_Sell1 = Sell_Signal[0]
    for i=0 to 150
        if (Sell_Signal[i] == 1)
            Base_Sell1 = 5
            break
    Base_Sell1

B_Sell = fun_check(Sell_Signal)
```

My function always returns the value as 1, but it should return a value as **5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `:` while assigning values to Base_Sell1 in the loop as Base_Sell1 is mutable variable

It should be:

```
Base_Sell1 := 5
```